# Populating Seaborn subplots using an array

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn

The **att_sales** table has 3 fields *item*,*qty* and *yr_mon*. The ***buckets(i)*** function returns a list of 20 SKUs(list of item values). A group by function is used to find the monthly sales for each of these SKUs
and then churns out a violinplot. The exercise wors fine till this point.

I am trying to visualize the monthly sales for about 200 SKUs along 10 subplots.To do this I intended an iterator to run from 1 through 10 and populate each of the subplots.The code below populates the last subplot out of 10 empty ones. How do I go about achieving this?

```
fig, (axis1) = plt.subplots(5,2,figsize=(15,30))
plt.xticks(rotation=45)
s=att_sales[['item','qty','yr_mon']]
s=s[s.item.isin(buckets(i))]
s=s.groupby(['item','yr_mon'], as_index=False).qty.sum()
sns.violinplot(x="item", y="qty", data=s)
```

**Edit1**: On implmenting @Ted's solution I got an error `min() arg is an empty sequence` when the for loop ran from 0 to n. Changing the for loop to run between 1 and n, provides most the solution but not quite.[image]

I need to know how to increase the size of the overall plot and of the individual subplots, and also change the orientation of the xticks to 45 degrees.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a simplified example that I think you can tweak to make it work for you. I am using the `tips` dataset in seaborn and plotting 4 different violin plots based on what day it is. I have also created a buckets function that returns a single element list of one day.

When the figure is created with `fig, axes = plt.subplots(2,2,figsize=(10,10))`, it returns both a matplotlib figure object which is stored into `fig` and a 2 dimensional numpy array of matplotlib axes objects which is stored in `axes`. To get the top left plot you would do `axes[0, 0]`. If you wanted the bottom right hand plot you would do `axes[1, 1]`. If you created a 5 row by 2 column figure `axes[3,0]` would be the plot on the 4th row and first column.

```
# create function that will return a list of items
# this particular example returns just a list of one element
def buckets(i):
    return [tips.day.unique()[i]]

# load dataset and create figure
tips = sns.load_dataset("tips")
num_plots = 4
fig, axes = plt.subplots(2,2,figsize=(10,10))

# iterate through all axes and create a violin plot
for i in range(num_plots):
    df = tips[tips.day.isin(buckets(i))]
    row = i // 2
    col = i % 2
    ax_curr = axes[row, col]
    sns.violinplot(x="sex", y="tip", data=df, ax=ax_curr)
    ax_curr.set_title(buckets(i))
```

[image]

Note that in this particular example you can use a facet grid which will do the same exact thing as what I did by plotting each day in a separate plot. You can take advantage of the facet grid if you label each bucket of SKUs a unique id. See the [very last example on this page](http://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.violinplot.html)

Comment: I was able to recreate most of this, there are a few niggles that would not succumb to any amount of coaxing.
The above snippet throws an error in the line `sns.boxplot(x="item", y="qty", data=s1, ax=ax_curr)`  : `min() arg is an empty sequence`.
On implementing the same code with the for loop iterating from 1 to n gives me the subplots, except the first subplot is still empty.

Comment: Iterate from 0 to n-1 not 1 to n. This is why your first subplot is empty.

Comment: It throws this error `ValueError: min() arg is an empty sequence` when I try iterating from 0 to n-1